# Facebook login in an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering how things should work when using facebook login in an iOS app.

I have set up a trial app in order to understand the facebook login process within an iOS app.

I have a “Login with Facebook” button. When I tap it for the first time, it goes asking for permissions, then I tap YES and it comes back to my app.
At this point all is fine, I have a “Log out” button. I tap it, I get logged out as expected and can see the “Login with Facebook” button again.

Now here comes the question. When I tap  the “Login with Facebook” button for the 2nd (or Nth) time, it shows me the facebook Confirm page displaying:
“You have already authorized THIS APP”
with a Cancel and an OK button.
Is this the way it should be?

It seems to me that the user knows he has already authorized THIS APP and does not need to be prompted each time.
In other words after tapping the “Login with Facebook” button it should not go through the facebook Confirm page.

Am I wrong?

If NO, why is this happening in my app?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to behave differently? Or would it be considered wrong?

Comment: You cannot change it.  It is up to Facebook.

Comment: That behavior is completely normal and it is the same behavior you will see in most production apps today. If you are using Facebook's FBLoginView, trust that they are handling everything properly. :)

Comment: OK. In that case I'll stick to that and it is going to make my life simple. Thanks.